# Cannot subscribe data from my API backend (angular)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, rxjs

I'm new to angular and ionic and i have to develop an application that can connect to a backend and get users data.
The application is able to extract user data, but not to save them in a variable
with subscribe method.

The PeopleService:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',

})


export class PeopleService {

      public activeProject:ReplaySubject<any> = new ReplaySubject(1);
      public people: any;

  constructor(public http: HttpClient ){
    console.log("Ciaooo");
  }

  getPeople() {

        this.http.get('.....................').pipe(map(res => res)).subscribe(res => this.activeProject.next(res));
        return this.activeProject;
  }



}
```

Home:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {PeopleService} from '../../people-service.service';
import { ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';


console.log("ouu");
@Component({
  selector: 'app-start-p',
  templateUrl: './start-p.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./start-p.page.scss'],
  providers: [PeopleService]
})

export class StartPPage implements OnInit {
  //public people : any;

   public people : any;



  constructor(public peopleService : PeopleService){
    console.log("Start p page costruito richiamo loadPeople");
  }

  ngOnInit() {


    this.people = null;
    console.log("loadPeople avviato, provo a inviare richiesta pacchetti a peopleService.getPeople");
    this.peopleService.getPeople();

 
    this.peopleService.activeProject.subscribe(active => {this.people = active, console.log(active)});
    console.log(this.people);
  }

}
```

The return JSON is like this:

```html
{"people": [{"gender":"female","name":{"title":"miss","first":"willemien","last":"heslinga"},"email":"willemien.heslinga@example.com"},{"gender" : "male", "name":{"title":"monsieur","first":"bernard","last":"olivier"},"email":"bernard.olivier@example.com"}]}
```

My app can read the json file, but can't save it. Runs the console.log but fails to put active in this.people

Comment: If you look at [Parent and children communicate via a service](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service) as an example, you'll see that you wouldn't subscribe directly to a `Subject<T>`. You would instead expose an observable (`asObservable()`) based on the subject from the service and subscribe that to that instead. Also, why even use a subject in your example, why not just consume the data of `getPeople()` directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try restructuring this set up a little to bit to keep it simple and get it working. As mention in the comment lets work on consuming `getPeople()` directly. Looking like the following. Be sure to import `Observable` from RxJS.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

private getPeople():Observable<any> {
 return this.http.get(//filler details//).pipe(map(data => data)
 );
}
```

Notice the function above is set to return an `Observable' which means in your component you can subscribe to it directly looking like so.

```
this.peopleService.getPeople().subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data); // is good, should show you people.
}, error => {
  console.log(error); // HttpError will provide error and type.
});
```

This removes the complicated logic involving the `subject` while giving you the required functionality. Any issues drop a comment. BR.

Comment: Thankssss, I wrote: this.peopleService.getPeople().subscribe(data => {
       console.log(data),
      this.people = data.people;    // It Works!!
    }, error => {
       console.log(error); // HttpError will provide error and type.
    });

Comment: Glad it helped :- )